# Why my Django-Rest-Framework post method do not have the fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In the Django-Rest-Framework API, I can not use post for testing, I don't know why there is no the post fields.

[image]

[image]

---

My View:

```
class WHMCSPhysicalServerIPMIManagementAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = WHMCSPhysicalServerIPMIManageSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def post(self, request):
        """

        :param request:

        action:
        physical_server_name:

        :return:
        """

        try:

            physical_server_name = request.query_params.get('physical_server_name')
            action = request.query_params.get('action')

            if not physical_server_name or not action:
                return Response(data="invalid request data", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            physical_server = PhysicalServer.objects.get(name=physical_server_name)

            msg = ipmi_management_handler({'action': action, 'physical_server_id': physical_server.id})

            return Response(data=msg, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return_data = "fail" if e.args == () else e.args[0]
            return Response(data=return_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

My serializers:

```
class WHMCSPhysicalServerIPMIManageSerializer(Serializer):
    physical_server_name = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)  
    action = serializers.CharField(write_only=True) 
    whmcs_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

My url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^whmcs/physicalserver/ipmi_management/$', WHMCSPhysicalServerIPMIManagementAPIView.as_view(), name='whmcs-physicalserver-ipmi_management'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `APIView` and you didn't implement the `GET` method, so DRF won't be able to render the API interface with the fields you want to post. It'd be appropriate for you to use [`CreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of confusion here. The POST data is in `request.data` / `request.post`.

For a simple example have a look [at the docs.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question. The `APIView` does not implement the `get` method by default and therefore won't be able to receive a `GET` request in order to list the fields. On the example you provided, a `get` method is implemented.

Comment: Fair, OP is asking about `POST` though. I link to the example docs for guidance as I'm not sure the question asked is actual the question.